# Paypal showing invalid quantity error when uploading shopping cart

Tags: html, paypal, e-commerce

I have made a paypal form to upload my custom shopping cart to paypal so customers can pay using payapal, however everytime I try to use it I am getting the following error on the paypal website:

"You have entered an invalid quantity value. A quantity value must be an integer greater than or equal to one."

Here is my code:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
    <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
    <input type="hidden"name="business" value="websales@myemail.co.uk">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Multi-Purpose Grease - Renolit" >
    <input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="4.13" >
    <input type="hidden" name="shipping_1" value="1.00" >
    <input type="hidden" name="quantity_1" value="1" >
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name_2" value="Blue Roll six pack, seconds" >
    <input type="hidden" name="amount_2" value="8.00" >
    <input type="hidden" name="shipping_2" value="1.00" >
    <input type="hidden" name="quantity_2" value="1" >
    <input type="hidden" name=" currency_code " value="GBP">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="KJXKVWA5MPEBY">
    <input type= "image"src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/GB/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online.">
</form>
```

If anyone has any ideas it would be much appreciated, this has been driving me mad!

Comment: Can I ask how have you created that code? Have you used the [PayPal](http://paypal.com) Buttons Creation Page or you coded yourself?

Comment: [Use this link to go to the buttons page](https://www.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/customerprofileweb?cmd=_button-management).

Comment: I used paypals button generator, and then folled their instructions in the integration guide here: https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/cart_upload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing cart upload buttons with the cart upload command.  The cart upload command should not have a hosted button id variable in it.  It would need to look like the following.

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="my_email@my_site.com">

<input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Football T-Shirt">
<input type="hidden" name="quantity_1" value="4">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="1.00">
<input type="hidden" name="on0_1" value="Color">
<input type="hidden" name="os0_1" value="Red">
<input type="hidden" name="on1_1" value="Size">
<input type="hidden" name="os1_1" value="Small">

<input type="hidden" name="item_name_2" value="Notebook">
<input type="hidden" name="quantity_2" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_2" value="2.00">
<input type="hidden" name="on0_2" value="Number of Pages">
<input type="hidden" name="os0_2" value="200">
<input type="hidden" name="on1_2" value="Type">
<input type="hidden" name="os1_2" value="3 Ring">

<input type="submit" value="PayPal">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I see where I have been going wrong then. The reason why I attempted to use the cart upload buttons is because I wanted the cart to be encrypted, by using the code you have provided above a user is able to edit the amount value which will enable them to make fraudulent payments, is there any way I can avoid this whilst keeping my custom cart?

Comment: You could either keep track of the items on your side, and not pass them over to PayPal.  Then you could just use a Pay Now/Buy Now button that you could encrypt so that the buyer can not modify the amounts.  You could also use Express Checkout, which would use API and you can prevent the buyer from modifying the amounts and etc.  Otherwise there is also the method of encrypting your own buttons, https://ppmts.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/502/kw/encrypted%20payments